# insert into table with split the string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I want to insert my split string into my table as you can see :

```
create table #Organization
(
    organizationId bigint, 
     provienceId bigint, 
     CityId bigint, 
      TownId bigint 

)
Insert Into #Organization  ( organizationId) 
 select  p.value from  string_split('1,2,3', ',') p
Insert Into #Organization  ( provienceId) 
 select  p.value from  string_split('1,2,3', ',') p
Insert Into #Organization  ( CityId) 
 select  p.value from  string_split('1,2,3', ',') p
Insert Into #Organization  ( TownId) 
 select  p.value from  string_split('1,2,3', ',') p
```

My expected result is something like this :

```
1   1     1   1
2   2     2   2
3   3     3   3
```

But it returns this :

[image]

Comment: You need an update statement for second and third statement

Comment: @PrashantPimpale how can i update the records?

Comment: Is there only three values every time or this is not real data?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it is not real data it can be changed

Comment: yes exactly, So can you provide sample data that you are actually dealing with?

Comment: Your insert statment has 3 columns and your table has 4 columns. Please define what the columns are in the insert statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm reading into your question, but I suspect you want to split your string into columns

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeColName varchar(max)) 
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 ('1,2,3')
,('A,B,C')
,('Dog,Cat,Pony')

Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeColName ,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Pos1    Pos2    Pos3
1       2       3
A       B       C
Dog     Cat     Pony
```

Comment: if i want to change the 1 2 3 ,4 5 6 , 7 8 9 to  1 4 7 ,2 5 8 , 3 6 9 ,what should i do ?

Comment: Are you looking for matrix manipulations?  Perhaps edit your question and add a more distinct data sample and desired results.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Happy to help  ... I guess  :)

Comment: Hi again ,in fact in my question i expect these result ,1 1 1 1,2 2 2 2 ,3 3 3 3 ,could you please help me how can i get this result?

Comment: i changed my question

Comment: @EhsanAkbar If you have 2016+ then Gordon's answer is correct.  Otherwise here is a dbFiddle   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aff5f7756162856816c5ba25578c028f

Answer (score 2):

Insert is inserting three rows, one for each value.  If you want to combine them into columns, you need to pivot them or (as I prefer) use aggregation.

You also have a table with four columns but only seem to be inserting three, so I suspect you want:

```
create table #Organization (
    organizationId int identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    provinceId int, 
    CityId int, 
    TownId int 
);
```

(I don't see a need for `bigint` for this example.)

Obviously, the simplest solution is not to use strings:

```
Insert Into #Organization (provinceId, CityId, TownId) 
    values (1, 2, 3);
```

But if you are using strings, you can try:

```
Insert Into #Organization (provinceId, CityId, TownId) 
    select provinceId, CityId, TownId
    from (values('1,2,3')) v(str) cross apply
         (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then p.value end) as provinceid,
                 max(case when seqnum = 2 then p.value end) as cityid,
                 max(case when seqnum = 3 then p.value end) as townid                 
          from (select p.*,
                       row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + p.value + ',', ',' + v.str + ',')) as seqnum
                from string_split(v.str, ',') p
               ) p
         ) s;
```

Note that there is an issue with using `string_split()` for this purpose, because it does not "remember" the position of the substring in the original string.  This attempts to get around this problem by using `charindex()`.  In your case, this will work, because the values are all numbers.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c7fc0fde6ea520ceca1d98ad778e4425) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Expecting an answer from you!

Comment: Thank you ,but i want to say the 1,2,3 is an example it can be changed to other values

Comment: @EhsanAkbar . . . And nothing in this answer precludes that.  Did you look at the db<>fiddle?  It has examples of other values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pivot to transform the columns into rows. Like:

```
INSERT INTO #organization 
            (provinceid, 
             cityid, 
             townid) 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT p.value, 
               RowN = Row_number() 
                        OVER ( 
                          ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM   String_split('1,2,3', ',') p) a 
       PIVOT (Max(a.value) 
             FOR rown IN ([1], 
                          [2], 
                          [3])) b
```

Comment: Hi again ,in fact in my question i expect these result ,1 1 1 1,2 2 2 2 ,3 3 3 3 ,could you please help me how can i get this result?