# SQL Server - Splitting a single, variable length column that is delimited with a / into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to split this field into columns separating at the '/' character. 
The string contains the Company Name/Location/Cost Center/Department/Job

Here is a sample:

```
JSM MFG/Stearns Blg/Operations/Shipping/Packer

JSM MFG/Birch Lane Blg/Maintenance/Electrical/Electrician II
```

The desired output is:

```
JSM MFG, Stearns Blg, Operations, Shipping, Packer
```

into their respective separate columns.

This would be combined with other columns, too, employee number, rate of pay etc.. which are just direct selects.

I have found a few different SQL excerpts but nothing that I could see that covers multiple delimiters with variable length in one string.

Thanks in advance,
Doug

Comment: *"I have found a few different SQL excerpts but nothing that I could see that covers multiple delimiters with variable length in one string."* What about [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) or [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)? What have you tried and why didn't it work? Considering this is one of the most asked questions, I more than suspect there's already an answer.

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160277/insert-into-table-with-split-the-string-in-sql/54160417#54160417  ... easy to expand

Comment: Really though, you should be fixing your design and not storing delimited data in your table(s) at all.

Comment: @Larnu It seems OP is trying to fix the data.  Over the years, we've had to consume horrible external data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that maybe you can build on. It uses the **SQL Server 2016+** `string_split()` table value function to split the string into fields, which are then mapped into columns on a table you want to update.

```
declare @empId int = 123456 -- Let's assume a table Employee you want to update.

-- You get the values you want to split from somewhere.
declare @example varchar(max) = 'JSM MFG/Stearns Blg/Operations/Shipping/Packer'

-- SQL Server 2016+ has a handy string_split() table function we can use.
-- We'll dump the split values into a temp table.
select value into #tmp from string_split(@example, '/')

-- We now retroactively add an identity column to the temp table,
-- so we can tell which positions the values map to.
alter table #tmp add i int identity(1,1)


-- And now, a cursor to iterate over the split values.

declare @i int
declare @value varchar(max)

declare split_cursor cursor for 
select i, value from #tmp

open split_cursor  
fetch next from split_cursor into @i, @value 

while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin  

    -- We know which values correspond to which positions in the Employee table,
    -- thanks to the identity integer we added to the temp table above.
    if (@i = 1)
    begin
        update Employee set Employer = @value where EmpId = @empId
    end
    else if (@i = 2)
    begin
        update Employee set Building = @value where EmpId = @empId
    end
    -- ETC...

    fetch next from split_cursor into @i, @value
end 

close split_cursor  
deallocate split_cursor
```

Comment: This may not be the most efficient solution possible, but it's not intended to be. It's intended to show what is possible, and who knows? Something like this may well be good enough, and that's often all that is needed in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than 1 way to do this.

Here's a demonstration of some:

> ```
> create table Test (
>  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>  col nvarchar(100)
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into Test (col) values
> ('abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno'),
> ('s/t/u/f/f'),
> ('w/h/y'),
> (null);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, 
>  s1 AS [CompanyName], 
>  s2 AS [Location],
>  s3 AS [Cost Center],
>  s4 AS [Department],
>  s5 AS [Job]
> FROM Test t
> OUTER APPLY
> (
>     SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4, s5
>     FROM (VALUES (col+'/')) q(s0)
>     CROSS APPLY (select case when charindex('/',s0)>0 then left(s0, charindex('/',s0)-1) end s1, case when charindex('/',s0)>0 then charindex('/',s0) end p1) a1
>     CROSS APPLY (select case when p1>0 and charindex('/',s0,p1+1)>0 then substring(s0, p1+1, charindex('/',s0,p1+1)-p1-1) end s2, case when p1>0 then charindex('/',s0,p1+1) end p2) a2
>     CROSS APPLY (select case when p2>0 and charindex('/',s0,p2+1)>0 then substring(s0, p2+1, charindex('/',s0,p2+1)-p2-1) end s3, case when p2>0 then charindex('/',s0,p2+1) end p3) a3
>     CROSS APPLY (select case when p3>0 and charindex('/',s0,p3+1)>0 then substring(s0, p3+1, charindex('/',s0,p3+1)-p3-1) end s4, case when p3>0 then charindex('/',s0,p3+1) end p4) a4
>     CROSS APPLY (select case when p4>0 and charindex('/',s0,p4+1)>0 then substring(s0, p4+1, charindex('/',s0,p4+1)-p4-1) end s5) a5
> ) a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | CompanyName | Location | Cost Center | Department | Job 
> -: | :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :--------- | :---
>  1 | abc         | def      | ghi         | jkl        | mno 
>  2 | s           | t        | u           | f          | f   
>  3 | w           | h        | y           | null       | null
>  4 | null        | null     | null        | null       | null
> ```

> ```
> select id,
>  [1] AS [CompanyName], 
>  [2] AS [Location],
>  [3] AS [Cost Center],
>  [4] AS [Department],
>  [5] AS [Job]
> from Test t
> outer apply (
>    select *
>    from
>    (
>      select value
>      , row_number() over (order by (select 0)) n
>      from string_split(t.col,'/') s
>    ) src
>    pivot (
>      max(value) 
>      for n in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
>   ) pvt
> ) a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | CompanyName | Location | Cost Center | Department | Job 
> -: | :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :--------- | :---
>  1 | abc         | def      | ghi         | jkl        | mno 
>  2 | s           | t        | u           | f          | f   
>  3 | w           | h        | y           | null       | null
>  4 | null        | null     | null        | null       | null
> ```

> ```
> select id,
>  s1 AS [CompanyName], 
>  s2 AS [Location],
>  s3 AS [Cost Center],
>  s4 AS [Department],
>  s5 AS [Job]
> from Test t
> outer apply (
>    select 
>      s1 = x0.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)')
>    , s2 = x0.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')
>    , s3 = x0.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)')
>    , s4 = x0.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)')
>    , s5 = x0.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)')
>    from 
>    (
>        select 
>        cast(('<x>'+ replace(col,'/','</x><x>') +'</x>') as xml) x0
>    ) q
> ) a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | CompanyName | Location | Cost Center | Department | Job 
> -: | :---------- | :------- | :---------- | :--------- | :---
>  1 | abc         | def      | ghi         | jkl        | mno 
>  2 | s           | t        | u           | f          | f   
>  3 | w           | h        | y           | null       | null
>  4 | null        | null     | null        | null       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fffce20773dd5c10f05d803478076845)*